# Вопрос по Android разметке

Tags: android, xml, разметка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать такую разметку, чтобы в верхней части layout`a находился один элемент, высотой с родительский контейнер минус 30dp, а в нижней другой элемент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта:

1. FrameLayout, в котором 2 вьюхи. у верхней match_parent для ширины и высоты и 30dp margin снизу. Вторая с layout_gravity bottom и высотой 30dp.
2. LinearLayout с двумя вьюхами и вертикальной ориентацией. у верхней height 0dp и weight 1. у нижней height 30dp.
3. вариант relative layout, озвученный выше. также необходимо указать логику привязки блоков.

Есть еще constraint layout. логика там похожа на relative layout

Answer (score 2):

Используйте RelativeLayout в качестве контейнера, указав для нижнего элемента параметры `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` и `android:layout_height="30dp"`